# How to select for duplicate product in woocomerce using sql

Tags: mysql

I am using woocomerce platform and I have duplicate entries of product name. Now, I want to see the categories_id,categories_name, products_name of duplicate "product_name" entered by the user group by a specific category name.

As I see on the database tables, here are the needed tables to view for the result:

Based on the table schema below:

```
  --------------------------
  | categories_description |
  --------------------------
   categories_id(PK)
   categories_name

  -----------------------
  | products_description |
  -----------------------
  products_id
  products_name


  ----------------------
  |products_to_categories |
  ----------------------- 
   products_id
   categories_id
```

My query:

```
  SELECT  prod.products_id, `products_name`, categories_name,      
  prodcat.categories_id , count(*) c
  FROM
   (products_description AS prod INNER JOIN  products_to_categories AS               
    prodcat ON prod.products_id=prodcat.products_id)
    INNER JOIN 
    categories_description AS catdesc ON    
    catdesc.categories_id=prodcat.categories_id AND categories_name= 'CARD  
    HOLDERS'  
    GROUP BY products_name 
    order by categories_name
```

The problem with my query is that, **it cannot display the list of entries duplicate product name**.

```
example Inputs:

 products_description 
 ---------------------------
 products_id  | products_name
      1            pens
      2            pens
      3            cars
      4            cars
      5            cars
      6            burgers

 products_to_categories
  -------------------------------
  products_id    |  categories_id
       1                 1
       2                 1
       3                 2
       4                 2
       5                 2
       6                 3     

  categories_description 
  ------------------------------
    categories_id | categories_name
        1                School Supply
        2                Vehicles
        3                 Foods

   =================================
   Expected Output
   =================================
   products_name  categories_name    categories_id     total_count
      pens          School Supply         1             2
      cars           Vehicles             2             3
      burgers           Foods             3             1
```

take a look at total count. It depends on number of occurrence in products_description table

Please help.

Comment: I don't see a `SELECT` in the subquery.  Does your query even run?  Show us sample input and desired output.

Comment: please see the modified question with samples.,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query which should *work* ...

```
SELECT t1.products_name,
       MAX(t3.categories_name) AS catgories_name,
       MAX(t2.categories_id) AS categories_id,
       COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM products_description t1
INNER JOIN products_to_categories t2
    ON t1.products_id = t2.products_id
INNER JOIN categories_description t3
    ON t2.categories_id = t3.categories_id
GROUP BY t1.products_name
```

...but even though this query should give the correct output, your database design has some flaws.  Instead of mapping each product entry to a separate entry in the category table, duplicate products should bear a duplicate ID, all of which map to the same category.  In short, your database is not normalized properly, so my query resorts to some non nice things, such as taking the `MAX` of certain columns while assuming that all values are the same.

Here is how I would modify your schema:

```
products_description

╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ id ║ products_id ║ products_name ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1  ║     1       ║     pens      ║
║ 2  ║     1       ║     pens      ║
║ 3  ║     2       ║     cars      ║
║ 4  ║     2       ║     cars      ║
║ 5  ║     2       ║     cars      ║
║ 6  ║     3       ║     burgers   ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╝

products_to_categories

╔═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ products_id ║ categories_id ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║     1       ║      1        ║
║     2       ║      2        ║
║     3       ║      3        ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Your third table can remain as is:

```
categories_description

╔═══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ categories_id ║ categories_name ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║      1        ║  School Supply  ║
║      2        ║  Vehicles       ║
║      3        ║  Foods          ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```